# Ruby Gem not found when using sudo as root

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cron, root

I have a VM, and on that VM I was having vnc/display issues when logging in as anything except root. Since I am the only person using it, I just do everything as root. I put together some ruby scripts I want to execute as root with crontab, and they fail to load ruby gems.

My root's crontab file looks something like this:

```
 0 0 * * * sudo -s ruby_file.rb
```

I read elsewhere that cron jobs run as a different user. That is why I added a 'sudo -s' even as the root user (it didn't work without it). If ruby_file.rb does not have any gems, it works great. However if ruby_file.rb has a require on a gem, I get the following error:

'require': cannot load such file -- (gem_name)

I think it is because the gem is installed on the root user, and I think cron jobs use an entirely different user, but I am not sure how to get the gem into the cron's user.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you use rvm?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. I was using rbenv for ruby (which I forgot to add to the initial details).

I had to add rbenv initialization to the crontab line, so it now looks like:

```
0 0 * * * export PATH=/root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; ruby_file.rb
```